# Validate a Cell Using a List: Application defined or object defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the code below to add validation lists to various cells. I thought it simple enough, but I get an error at the `Formula1:="Notes!A1" & finalRowNotes` line. The error is

> Application defined or object defined error

What am I missing?

```
finalRowNotes = Worksheets("Notes").Cells(1000000, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 4 To r - 1
    With Range("P" & i).Validation
      .Delete
      .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
      AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
      Operator:=xlBetween, _
      Formula1:="=Notes!A1:A" & finalRowNotes
      .IgnoreBlank = True
      .InCellDropdown = True
      .InputTitle = ""
      .ErrorTitle = ""
      .InputMessage = ""
      .ErrorMessage = ""
      .ShowInput = True
      .ShowError = True
    End With
  Next i
```

For what it's worth, here is what is in the Notes worksheet in cells `A1:A18`

```
Block volume not reported
Blocks
Blocks away
Blocks.  Foreign trades not incl. in volume or VWAP in this market
Could not inventory
Market closed
No foreign trades
Order canceled
Order complete
Order given after market
Order given mid-session
Out of limit
Out of limit, changed to market order after session closed
Out of limit-premium
Pending 1 day funding requirement
Pending custodian confirmation
Volume out of limit
Volume out of limit, limit reduced during session
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67336/discussion-on-question-by-matt-cremeens-validate-a-cell-using-a-list-applicatio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what to say, and I am sorry for wasting everyone's time, but when I restored this workbook to an earlier version, all was fine. All I can think to say is thanks to all who threw their hats in the ring and gave such generous efforts. I suppose my workbook became corrupted somehow because an older, yet identical one, worked as expected.

Comment: Still a valid answer to the problem! Don't worry about it!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the conversations in both the question and the first answer, I would recommend placing the following code in a module:

```
'Dimension your two variables
Dim Notes As Worksheet, Vali As Worksheet

'Set the variables equal to the sheet names.
Set Notes = Sheets("Notes")
Set Vali = Sheets("NAME OF VALIDATION SHEET")

'Changes the Sheet reference to the variable Notes and changed your syntax to Rows.Count
finalRowNotes = Notes.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Rows.Count is better method for last row of document
For i = 4 To r - 1
    'Added Vali to define the sheet
    With Vali.Range("P" & i).Validation
      .Delete
      .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
      AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
      Operator:=xlBetween, _
      Formula1:="=Notes!A1:A" & finalRowNotes
      .IgnoreBlank = True
      .InCellDropdown = True
      .InputTitle = ""
      .ErrorTitle = ""
      .InputMessage = ""
      .ErrorMessage = ""
      .ShowInput = True
      .ShowError = True
    End With
  Next i
```

Comment: Actually, it is in its own sub. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No, I am saying you should put your code into a "module" (as in the entire sub) and add definitions for each sheet you are working with.  This code is simply to be added to your existing sub (obviously don't duplicate the parts you already have).  I will edit to comment on my changes.

Comment: Are there any blanks in the range `"=Notes!A1:A" & finalRowNotes`?

Comment: You haven't put this in a worksheet module have you?

Comment: No, no blanks in that range.

Comment: I have tried to duplicate this error by putting the code in both sheet's code and a module.  Each one works correctly.  When your code errors, what is the value of your variables?  Try debugging the variable values or having a `MsgBox` popup with the values of `r`, `i`, and `finalRowNotes`.

Answer (score 0):

You use operator xlBetween. I guess, you need xlEqual.

Answer (score 0):

just activate the range, it will solve the problem..

```
Vali.Range("P" & i).Activate
```